# Mahout - Seq2Sparse Single Reducer

Tags: hadoop, mahout

I've been running a seq2sparse job for many days now and it just doesn't finish. The primary reason being that most of the "sub-jobs" have only 1 reducer, while there are many many mappers for each job.

I specified --numReducers = n while invoking seq2sparse from the command line, but that attribute is used only in some places such as `MakePartialVectors` but not for sub jobs like `Prune Vectors`.

What could be the reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I looked in the code and realized that the `numReducers` variable is not passed along to all the sub jobs and therefore those jobs get created with the default reduce capacity i.e 1

To get around this limitation, one should simply specify the variable `-Dmapred.reduce.tasks=n` while invoking the job from the command line along with the `--numReducers=n` parameter

Its necessary to also specify the `numReducers` since by default the Mahout CLI takes it to be one.

So an example of a command would be

`./mahout seq2sparse -Dmapred.reduce.tasks=10 -i seq-files -o vectors -nv -wt tfidf -ng 2 --numReducers 10 --maxDFPercent 90 --minDF 2 --norm 2 --minLLR 20`